# Проблемы с приложением Qt на Windows 10

Tags: c++, qt, vector

Написал приложение на qt на windows 7, перенес на 10 винду,скомпилировал,запустил и на каждом втором цикле прохода по вектору, например вот в этих двух

```
for(int i=0;i<=for_step_x.size();i++)//here
    {
        scalar_product=l_oz*l_st[i]+m_oz*m_st[i]+n_oz*n_st[i];
        angle_arccos.push_back(acos(scalar_product));

    }


    for(int i=0;i<=angle_arccos.size();i++)//here
    {
        if((angle_arccos[i]*180/pi)<view_angle)
        {
            result_alpha.push_back(for_step_x[i]);
            result_beta.push_back(for_step_y[i]);
```

вылезает ошибка

```
ASSERT failure in QVector<T>::operator[]: "index out of range", file C:\Qt\5.6\mingw49_32\include/QtCore/qvector.h, line 427
```

на 7 винде такого соответственно не наблюдалось, в чем причина не пойму. лечится это костылями типа

```
for(int i=0;i<for_step_x.size()-1;i++)// для звездной величины
            {
```

или в иных случаях , просто убиранием `=` из `<=`

так же, вот на таком коде

```
 QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,
                                                    tr("Save jpg"), ".",
                                                    tr("jpg files (*.jpg)"));
```

т.е когда вызывается файлдиалог и я выбираю место и имя файла для сохранения в вывод приложения вылазят такие штуки

```
shell\comdlg32\fileopensave.cpp(9456)\COMDLG32.DLL!76D90750: (caller: 76D83458) ReturnHr[PreRelease](1) tid(13ec) 80070490 Элемент не найден.
    CallContext:[\PickerModalLoop\InitDialog\FileDialogInitEnterpriseData] 
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](1) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(153)\thumbcache.dll!5B9C6270: (caller: 7653FEE9) ReturnHr[PreRelease](2) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](3) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(153)\thumbcache.dll!5B9C6270: (caller: 7653FEE9) ReturnHr[PreRelease](4) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(153)\thumbcache.dll!5B9C6270: (caller: 7653FEE9) ReturnHr[PreRelease](5) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(153)\thumbcache.dll!5B9C6270: (caller: 7653FEE9) ReturnHr[PreRelease](6) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(153)\thumbcache.dll!5B9C6270: (caller: 7653FEE9) ReturnHr[PreRelease](7) tid(13ec) 80030002 Не удается найти %1.
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](9) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](8) tid(2758) 8004B203 shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](10) tid(2758) 8004B203 shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](11) tid(2758) 8004B203 shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](12) tid(13ec) 80004005 Неопознанная ошибка
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](13) tid(2284) 8004B200     CallContext:[\PerformFullExtract] 
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](14) tid(2284) 8004B200     CallContext:[\PerformFullExtract] 
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](15) tid(2334) 8004B200     CallContext:[\PerformFullExtract] 
shell\ext\thumbnailcache\lib\thumbcacheapi.cpp(243)\thumbcache.dll!5B9ADFD9: (caller: 5B9AE191) ReturnHr[PreRelease](16) tid(2334) 8004B200
```

в чем может быть проблема? компиляторы вроде одинаковые

Comment: Для вектора индексы должны быть от 0 до (N-1). Где N - размер. Выход за пределы приводит к неопределенному поведению программы.

Comment: @alexolut, да, но в некоторых ошибка пропадает только тогда, когда добавляется -1 , а так же убирается = из <=, а тут уже теряется один элемент

Comment: Если индексы корректны как при записи в вектор, так и при чтении - никаких элементов теряться не должно. Но так как мы не видим полной картины, проблема может быть и в других местах кода.

Comment: Опеределённо выход за пределы массива приведёт к ошибки. Даже может привести к крешу программы. Ваши циклы не должны выходить за пределы вектора. Также прохода в повсем элементам вы можете использовать инератор или например foreach (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/containers.html#the-foreach-keyword).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изначально Вы неверно определили границы индексирования: от 0 до `size()`. Если у Вас контейнер содержит в себе N элементов, то индексы этих элементов можно представить следующим образом:

```
0..1..2..3.. ..N-2..N-1
```

Итого - N элементов. В цикле (в Вашем примере) на верхнюю границу налагается следующее условие: `i <= size()`. А это значит не что иное, как то, что на определенной итерации i станет равным N. Элемента N в контейнере нет - именно об этом Вам напомнил компилятор сообщением:

> ASSERT failure in QVector::operator[]: "index out of range"

Далее, Вы пытаетесь решить проблему - но слишком усердно принялись за это. Наложили на i следующее условие `< size() - 1`. Достаточно было просто убрать знак =, чтобы неравенство стало строгим. А так, Вы наложили ограничение, которое просто упускает последний элемент; иными словами, максимальное значение, которое может принять i:

`i(max) < size() - 1 => i(max) < N - 1 => i(max) = N - 2`

Контейнеры лучше обходить итераторами. Если Вам нужно изменение данных внутри цикла for - это обычный итератор, НЕ нужно - const_iterator.

---

Что касается getSaveFileName - странно, что Вам выдается сообщение "файл не найден" - то-ли потому что используете кириллицу (хотя не уверен, что дело в этом), то ли потому, что это сообщение относится не к этому коду. Оно специфично для getOpenFileName, для getSaveFileName "несуществование" файла - вполне ожидаемо, в документации по этому поводу так и написанно:

> This is a convenience static function that will return a file name
>   selected by the user. The file does not have to exist.